# Responsive with flex

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexbox

i am using flex to centre and position my element on my layers , but when switching to a small screen size , the element just get smaller while in bootstrap when i use `<col-md-4>` when the screen get smaller the div take the whole width , i wanna do something similar when the user switch to a small screen size(i didnt use bootstrap because its realy hard to centre 3 div of `<col-md-3>` in the middle of the page

```
<div class="container">
  <div>
  </div>
  <div>
  </div>
   <div>
  </div>
</div>
```

my css look like this

```
.container div {
  height:180px;
  width:180px;
  background-color:black;
  margin: 15px 15px;
}
```

Comment: You can add  flex-flow: wrap;  to the flexbox

Comment: oké i will test it thx for the answer

Answer (score 1):

You could use both `flex` and `media query` as below align them in center at certain screen resolution,

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container div {
  height: 180px;
  width: 180px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 15px 15px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:320px) {
  .container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
  </div>
  <div>
  </div>
  <div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Check this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qfddffuw/) `scale` that front and back to see changes in alignment.

Comment: @Hamid achori Check jsFiddle to do that using flex.

Comment: ah yes this solution work to and its allow me to center the div in the middle while in small screen size thx man

Comment: Welcome @Hamidachori :-), it works because change in flex direction using media query and alignment too.